# Magento 1:9 : Move order button from review div in onestepcheckout

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

I have recently moved to `LotusBreath` `OneStepCheckout`. I made a few `alterations` to the extension.

As soon as I moved the complete order `button` from the `review` div into another div, I was able to place multiple orders by clicking the button twice.

Does anyone know how you can move the `button` without affecting functionality?

Comment: Make sure your button is inside `<form>`

Comment: It is, unfortunately not that simple. I believe there is some scripts that happen as part of that button being pressed within the review div.